# Alterando index.jsp dinamicamente sem recarregar a pagina

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlet

Dentro da minha index.jsp possuo uma tabela que em uma de suas células e um iframe que exibe uma de minhas jsp, e dependendo do tipo de ação tomada pelo usuário ele muda qual e a pagina exibida dentro do iframe, gostaria de saber se tem como efetuar esta mudança sem recarregar a pagina.

pelo que pesquisei a forma de se fazer isso e em ajax, mas nao sei utilizar o ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há pelo menos três formas principais de alterar o conteúdo de um `frame` ou `iframe`.

## Alterar o atributo `src` com JavaScript

Imagine que você tem um frame assim:

```html
<iframe id="frame" src="http://servidor/pagina1" />
```

Então pode implementar uma função que acessa o frame através do seu `id` e altera o atributo `src`, que contém a URL exibida:

```js
function trocaPagina() {
    var f = document.getElementById('frame');
    f.src = 'http://servidor/pagina2';
}
```

Isso pode ser chamado através de algum link ou botão, por exemplo:

```html
<button type="button" onclick="trocaPagina()">Trocar conteúdo</button>
```

### [Demo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/Lw5h440t/)

## Através de um link (`a`) com o atributo `target`

Crie um frame com o atributo `name` definido, da seguinte forma:

```html
<iframe name="frame" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/" />
```

Então você pode abrir nele uma página qualquer quando o usuário clicar em um link, basta definir a URL no link e adicionar o atributo `target` com o mesmo valor do `name` do frame.

Exemplo:

```html
<a href="http://blog.jsfiddle.net/" target="frame">Trocar outro conteúdo</a>
```

### [Demo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/ysbtt217/)

## Através de um submit de formulário com o atributo `target`

Considerando o mesmo frame anterior com o atributo `name`:

```html
<iframe name="frame" src="http://doc.jsfiddle.net/" />
```

Então você pode abrir nele uma página qualquer quando o usuário submeter um formulário, basta definir a URL noa tributo `action` e o atributo `target` com o mesmo valor do `name` do frame.

Exemplo:

```html
<form action="http://jsfiddle.net/" target="frame">
    <button type="submit" onclick="trocaPagina()">Trocar conteúdo</button>
</form>
```

### [Demo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/ysbtt217/)

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode usar JavaScript para mudar o endereço do iframe sem ter que recarregar toda a pagina:

```
document.getElementById("id-do-iframe").src = "/nova-pagina.jsp?parametro=1";
```